# WP: how to remove version number in wp_enqueue_script?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to remove the version number from appearing in the URL generated by `wp_enqueue_script`. It seems like I should pass a `null` on the 4th parameter per http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', false, array(), null, false);
```

It's not working. I still see the version number. How do I remove that?

Also, how do I use `wp_enqueue_script` so that I get jQuery from the Google CDN?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can either use

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'URL', array(), '', false);
```

or

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'URL', array(), null, false);
```

or you can put a generic name placeholder

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'URL', array(), 'custom', false);
```

But particularly with "jquery" I would deregister the default if you want to replace it

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
$GoogleJqueryURI = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js';
wp_register_script('jquery', $GoogleJqueryURI, array(), 'custom', false);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Comment: What does this "custom" do?

Comment: This worked for me: `wp_register_script('jquery', $GoogleJqueryURI, array(), null, false);`. It need the URL not to contain a query string. Putting "custom" resulted in something like this: `?ver=custom`, which is not what I wanted.

Comment: custom doesn't do anything.  It is just a word placeholder for the Version.  Basically would show ?ver=custom where << version does not technically have to show an actual version number.

Comment: '' won't work, null worked.
Btw never use the external jquery version with WordPress, it will cause lots of conflict with inbuild WordPress jQuery

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
wp_register_script('jquery', ('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'), false, NULL);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

The $ver and $in_footer are optional.  So just leave them off.

Also, if you use the google cdn then it will be hard to hide the version any way, its in the url.

Comment: Yes, $ver is optional. But the default behavior is that it appears in the URL produced. I don't want the the query string. As for the Google CDN, it doesn't have the version in the query string, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

An example when **version is not added**.

```
wp_enqueue_script('element-plus', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/element-plus@1.1.0-beta.9/dist/index.full.min.js', null, null)
```

An output of code above will be:

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/element-plus@1.1.0-beta.9/dist/index.full.min.js' id='element-plus-js'></script>
```

According to documentation several variables are accepted:

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', string[] $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

If value for $`ver` is false (or not given), then automatically version of WP is used.

Answer (score -1):

```
function remove_css_js_version( $src ) {
    if( strpos( $src, '?ver=' ) )
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    return $src;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_css_js_version', 9999 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_css_js_version', 9999 );
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27780780)

Comment: This is not proper solution as you need to use correct value for variable #ver.