# How to remove jQuery version number in wp_enqueue_script for bundled jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've managed to remove version query strings from all js and css files (including the main style.css) but still can't remove it for bundled jQuery version (current is 1.11.0). I don't need it, my server manages caching properly. And **I don't want to dequeue it and replace with external jQuery library**.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062105/wp-how-to-remove-version-number-in-wp-enqueue-script/15062211#15062211) doesn't help.

I think it's possible (if possible at all) by altering the default WP behavior without modifying the core files. Any ideas which filter to use?

Comment: What problem is the version number being added causing? does WP change the version number on it's own, causing a trip to the server? At what point does the version number change? does it happen often enough for it to matter?

Comment: Looks like it only changes when you upgrade jQuery. Therefore, preventing it from being added is absolutely pointless, as the only time it will cause a trip to the server is when a trip to the server is needed.

Comment: @KevinB nope, there's no problem with extra trips or requests but there's some strange behavior. In the source I have style.css and right after it there's jQuery. But as I see in dev tools browser requests jQuery first, and then style.css which is completely wrong. I'm not 100% sure but chances are this is because of jQuery version string - I've dumped a page to static html and removed this query string, now browser loads resources in proper order.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that a querystring is impacting the order that things load.

Comment: @KevinB me too. But I don't have any alternative explanation. In source the order is - style.css, next jquery.js. Browser requests - jquery.js, then style.css. With a static html page (full copy) where I removed the query string everything is requested in proper order.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at start times, not end times? In my test case i see all three (my css, jquery, and bootstrapjs) all starting at the same exact time, and finishing at different times. changing the querystring isn't changing anything (i'm also always starting with empty cache)

Comment: To be clear, Yes, it does change the order in which they appear in the console, however it does not impact the order that they get loaded since they all start at the same time.

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools, Audits tab says: "The following external CSS files were included after an external JavaScript file in the document head. To ensure CSS files are downloaded in parallel, always include external CSS before external JavaScript." In Network tab looks fine - style is being initiated by line :12, script - line :13. In Timeline tab both resources have the exact same starting time 386ms.

Comment: I don't see that message with my test page

Comment: I'll prepare the same code for some of my live sites and test it. Maybe it's just a local server issue. It's better to test it in the wild with WebPageTest.org etc. Anyway, I still see this message. That's why I started digging... Thanks for your time!