# How to remove version number in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I need to remove my wordpress version in all location. Because I my client my not upgrade wordpress.

I got some reference link from stackoverflow itself [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062105/wp-how-to-remove-version-number-in-wp-enqueue-script) by enqueue script

But I am not interesting with jquery ajaxgoogleapis to do that. Any simple solution available? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress - remove Meta generator tags (theme)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335347/wordpress-remove-meta-generator-tags-theme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter to remove wordpress version number try this please in functions.php

```
function wp_remove_version() {

    return '';

   }

  add_filter('the_generator', 'wp_remove_version');
  remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
```

For Reference: check the link [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/the-right-way-to-remove-wordpress-version-number/)

Comment: Thanks naveen but it still showing on my dashboard! how to resolve this?

Comment: The above code will remove from head area and rss feed. 
Dono why you want to hide from dashboard. 
Anyway This may help to you http://www.iconwebsolutions.info/remove-hide-wordpress-framework-version-from-admin-dashboard-and-front-end-view-source/

Answer (score 2):

open functions.php from your theme and the following code

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your functions.php

```
function disable_version() {
   return '';
}

add_filter('the_generator','disable_version');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
```

and this code you have to hide all update notifications like plugins, wordpress upgrade etc.

```
function my_custom_admin_footer() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
    #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo, #wp-admin-bar-updates, #wp-admin-bar-comments, #wp-admin-bar-new-content,
    #dashboard_right_now .b-tags, 
    #dashboard_right_now .tags, #wpfooter,
    #dashboard_right_now .b-comments, 
    #dashboard_right_now .comments,#dashboard_right_now .b-posts, 
    #dashboard_right_now .posts,#dashboard_right_now .table_discussion, #screen-meta-links, .plugin-version-author-uri, .plugin-update-tr, .update-plugins, .update-nag, #wp-version-message, #dashboard_right_now .main p {
           display:none;
    }
    </style>'; 
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'my_custom_admin_footer');
```

Or you can do this same thing with installing this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-wordpress-updates/

Comment: Thanks purvik but it still showing on my dashboard! how to resolve this?

Comment: If you want to hide all wordpress update then you have to install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-wordpress-updates/