# All Loaded Files On Wordpress' function.php End with Wordpress Version Number

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I load bootstrap and other related files to WordPress from `functions.php` using this code:

```
function enqueue_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery','//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.min.js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_script');
```

It loads correctly but on the rendered html file, the bootstrap files end with version number of Wordpress. For example:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap.min.css-css'  href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: so it's not wrong actually. Did you faced any problem?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Look at the end of the rendered bootstrap line, it ends with ver=4.8.1. It should not be like that right?

Comment: @AlivetoDie, it is not clean. That's the problem. But is there any other implication?

Comment: Please see the codex documentation of `wp_enqueue_script` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and `wp_enqueue_style` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove version from your CSS/js  add below code to your active theme `function.php` file.

```
// Remove WP Version From Styles    
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'sdt_remove_ver_css_js', 9999 );
// Remove WP Version From Scripts
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'sdt_remove_ver_css_js', 9999 );

// Function to remove version numbers
function sdt_remove_ver_css_js( $src ) {
    if ( strpos( $src, 'ver=' ) )
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    return $src;
}
```

You can go for plugins also (check on google and you will found easily).One of them is given below:-

[CS Remove Version Number From CSS & JS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cs-remove-version-number-from-css-js/)

Note:- Check some other code options also:-

[WP: how to remove version number in wp_enqueue_script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062105/wp-how-to-remove-version-number-in-wp-enqueue-script)

Comment: Thank you. Saving your answer

Comment: @adi  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
wp_register_script('jquery-load', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js', array(), '3.2.1');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-load');

wp_register_script('bootstrap.min', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.3.7'); //
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.min'); // Enqueue it!
```

notice the 4 arguments in `wp_register_script`

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like below and reference from here [wp enqueue scripts](http://wp_enqueue_script(%20$handle,%20$src,%20$deps,%20$ver,%20$in_footer%20);)

```
function enqueue_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery','//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js', array(), '3.2.1');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.min.js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.3.7');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.min');
}
```

Please try it and let me know.
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_script');